# Class linked into start button won't run

Tags: java, class, user-interface, methods

In a GUI in Java, when I click a Start button, I want this main class WumpusWorld to run a certain method.  I then want the GUI to refresh and see a change.  At the moment, I click Start and nothing happens.  EDIT - I am going to give you guys the full classes I am using.  You should be able to run them in Eclipse.  I just want this program to do SOMETHING when I click start, because at the moment it is doing NOTHING.

WumpusWorld.java (main class)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;



public class WumpusWorld {


private static int size;
private static Node startpoint;
private static Node endpoint;
private static int mode;
//private static String[][] nodeTypes;
private static LinkedList<Node> thegrid;
private static WumpusGui wgui;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Show the GUI
    thegrid = new LinkedList<Node>();
    wgui = new WumpusGui();

    // Set an initial size*/
    setSize(5);
}

// Set up the grid
public static void setUpGrid() {

    thegrid.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            thegrid.add(new Node(i, j, "empty"));
        }
    }

    wgui.setGridSize(size);
    wgui.setGrid(thegrid);
}

/**
 * 
 */
public static void run() {
    mode = 0; // Manhattan Heuristic

    // Ensure that the grid is valid
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if(thegrid.get(i*size+j).isGoal()) {
                end++;
                endpoint = thegrid.get(i*size+j);
            } else if(thegrid.get(i*size+j).isRobot()) {
                start++;
                startpoint = thegrid.get(i*size+j);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!(start == 1 && end == 1)) {
        return;
    }

    Pathfinder pathf = new Pathfinder(thegrid);
    String temp = pathf.pathfind(startpoint, endpoint, mode);

    temp = temp.substring(1);
    temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length()-1);
    String[] result = temp.split("\\)\\(");
    int finalcounter = result.length;

    LinkedList<Node> victoryPath = new LinkedList<Node>();
    for (String a : result) {
        String[] b = a.split(",");
        victoryPath.add(new Node(Integer.parseInt(b[0]), Integer.parseInt(b[1]), "empty"));
        System.out.println("lol");
    }

    for(Node n : victoryPath) {
        thegrid.get(n.getX()*size + n.getY()).setType("path");
    }
}

// Setter for size
public static void setSize(int newSize) {
    size = newSize;
    setUpGrid();
}

public static void setStartPos(int x, int y) {
    // Remove the old start pos
    for(int i=0; i<size*size; i++) {
        if(thegrid.get(i).isRobot()) {
            thegrid.get(i).setType("empty");
            break;
        }
    }

    // Add the new pos
    thegrid.get((x*size) + y).setType("robot");
}

public static void setEndPos(int x, int y) {
    // Remove the old start pos
    for(int i=0; i<size*size; i++) {
        if(thegrid.get(i).isGoal()) {
            thegrid.get(i).setType("empty");
            break;
        }
    }

    // Add the new pos
    thegrid.get((x*size) + y).setType("goal");
}

public static void setObstacle(int x, int y) {
    // Add the obstacle
    thegrid.get((x*size) + y).setType("wall");
}

public static void removeObstacle(int x, int y) {
    // Add the obstacle
    thegrid.get((x*size) + y).setType("empty");
}

}
```

WumpusGui.java (JPanel)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.*;


public class WumpusGui extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// This GUI
private static WumpusGui wgui;

// Controls

// NxN Grid Input
private JPanel pnlLayoutGrid;
private JLabel lblGrid;
private JTextField txtGrid;
private JButton btnGrid;

// Obstacle input
private JPanel pnlLayoutObstacles;
private JLabel lblObstacleX;
private JTextField txtObstacleX;
private JLabel lblObstacleY;
private JTextField txtObstacleY;
private JButton btnObstacleAdd;
private JLabel lblObstacleLog;
private JPanel pnlLayoutObstacleButtons;

// Start and end box positions
private JPanel pnlStartEndPos;

private JPanel pnlStartPos;
private JLabel lblStartX;
private JTextField txtStartX;
private JLabel lblStartY;
private JTextField txtStartY;
private JButton btnStartPos;

private JPanel pnlEndPos;
private JLabel lblEndPos;
private JLabel lblEndX;
private JTextField txtEndX;
private JLabel lblEndY;
private JTextField txtEndY;
private JButton btnEndPos;

// Start and stop buttons
private JPanel pnlStartStop;
private JButton btnStart;
private JButton btnStop;

// Display
private JPanel pnlDisplay;
private JPanelGrid pnlGraphics;
private JLabel pnlText;

// Window layouts
private JPanel pnlTop;
private JPanel pnlTopLeft;
private JPanel pnlTopRight;

public WumpusGui() {
    // Set up window
    setTitle("Wumpus World GUI");
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    // Set up controls
    Dimension d = new Dimension(50, 25);

    // Set up basic layout
    pnlTop = new JPanel();
    add(pnlTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    pnlTopLeft = new JPanel();
    pnlTopLeft.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlTopLeft, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    pnlTopRight = new JPanel();
    pnlTop.add(pnlTopLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
    pnlTop.add(pnlTopRight, BorderLayout.EAST);

    // Set up NxN grid controls
    pnlLayoutGrid = new JPanel();
    pnlLayoutGrid.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Grid"));
    pnlTopLeft.add(pnlLayoutGrid);

    lblGrid = new JLabel("Grid size");
    txtGrid = new JTextField();
    txtGrid.setPreferredSize(d);
    btnGrid = new JButton("Set size");

    pnlLayoutGrid.add(lblGrid);
    pnlLayoutGrid.add(txtGrid);
    pnlLayoutGrid.add(btnGrid);

    // Set up start and end position controls
    pnlStartEndPos = new JPanel();
    pnlStartEndPos.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlStartEndPos, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    pnlTopLeft.add(pnlStartEndPos);

    pnlStartPos = new JPanel();
    pnlStartPos.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Start position"));
    pnlStartEndPos.add(pnlStartPos);

    lblStartX = new JLabel("X: ");
    txtStartX = new JTextField();
    txtStartX.setPreferredSize(d);
    lblStartY = new JLabel("Y: ");
    txtStartY = new JTextField();
    txtStartY.setPreferredSize(d);
    btnStartPos = new JButton("Set");

    pnlStartPos.add(lblStartX);
    pnlStartPos.add(txtStartX);
    pnlStartPos.add(lblStartY);
    pnlStartPos.add(txtStartY);
    pnlStartPos.add(btnStartPos);

    pnlEndPos = new JPanel();
    pnlEndPos.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("End position"));
    pnlStartEndPos.add(pnlEndPos);

    lblEndX = new JLabel("X: ");
    txtEndX = new JTextField();
    txtEndX.setPreferredSize(d);
    lblEndY = new JLabel("Y: ");
    txtEndY = new JTextField();
    txtEndY.setPreferredSize(d);
    btnEndPos = new JButton("Set");

    pnlEndPos.add(lblEndX);
    pnlEndPos.add(txtEndX);
    pnlEndPos.add(lblEndY);
    pnlEndPos.add(txtEndY);
    pnlEndPos.add(btnEndPos);

    // Set up obstacles controls
    pnlLayoutObstacles = new JPanel();
    pnlLayoutObstacles.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Obstacles"));
    pnlLayoutObstacles.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlLayoutObstacles, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    pnlTopRight.add(pnlLayoutObstacles);

    lblObstacleX = new JLabel("X: ");
    txtObstacleX = new JTextField();
    txtObstacleX.setPreferredSize(d);
    lblObstacleY = new JLabel("Y: ");
    txtObstacleY = new JTextField();
    txtObstacleY.setPreferredSize(d);
    btnObstacleAdd = new JButton("Add");

    pnlLayoutObstacleButtons = new JPanel();
    pnlLayoutObstacles.add(pnlLayoutObstacleButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    pnlLayoutObstacleButtons.add(lblObstacleX);
    pnlLayoutObstacleButtons.add(txtObstacleX);
    pnlLayoutObstacleButtons.add(lblObstacleY);
    pnlLayoutObstacleButtons.add(txtObstacleY);
    pnlLayoutObstacleButtons.add(btnObstacleAdd);

    // Graphical display
    pnlGraphics = new JPanelGrid();
    pnlGraphics.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    pnlGraphics.setN(10);
    pnlGraphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(pnlGraphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Add the start button
    btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    pnlTopRight.add(btnStart, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Button setup
    btnGrid.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                WumpusWorld.setSize(Integer.parseInt(txtGrid.getText()));
                pnlGraphics.repaint();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                // Nothing
            }
        }
    });

    btnStartPos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                WumpusWorld.setStartPos(Integer.parseInt(txtStartX.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtStartY.getText()));
                pnlGraphics.repaint();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                // Nothing
            }
        }
    });

    btnEndPos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                WumpusWorld.setEndPos(Integer.parseInt(txtEndX.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtEndY.getText()));
                pnlGraphics.repaint();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                // Nothing
            }
        }
    });

    btnObstacleAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                WumpusWorld.setObstacle(Integer.parseInt(txtObstacleX.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtObstacleY.getText()));
                pnlGraphics.repaint();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                // Nothing
            }
        }
    });

    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                WumpusWorld.run();
                pnlGraphics.repaint();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                // Nothing
            }
        }
    });

    pnlGraphics.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // Get X and Y
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();

            // Left click = add obstacle
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                pnlGraphics.addObstacle(x, y);
            // Right click = remove obstacle
            } else {
                pnlGraphics.removeObstacle(x, y);
            }
            pnlGraphics.repaint();
        }

        // These methods are not used
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    });

    // finish off the window
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void drawGrid(int n) {
    // Draw the base grid
    Graphics g;
}

public static WumpusGui get() {
    return wgui;
}

public void setGridSize(int size) {
    pnlGraphics.setN(size);
    txtGrid.setText(String.valueOf(size));
}

// Set the grid in the graphics display
public void setGrid(LinkedList<Node> thegrid) {
    pnlGraphics.setObstacles(thegrid);
}

// Private class used for displaying the grid visually
private class JPanelGrid extends JPanel {

    private int n; // width/height of grid

    private LinkedList<Node> obstacles;

    private LinkedList<Clickable> clickables = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Set up dimensions
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int gridX = 10;
        int gridY = 10;
        int gridW = width-20;
        int gridH = height-20;

        // Draw the grid's background
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(gridX, gridY, gridW, gridH);

        // Empty the clickable list
        clickables.clear();

        // Draw cells
        int nodePointer = 0;

        if(obstacles != null) {
            for(int i=0, ii=0; ii<n; i+=(gridW/n), ii++) {
                for(int j=0, jj=0; jj<n; j+=(gridH/n), jj++) {

                    // Set the color depending on the node's type
                    if(obstacles.get(nodePointer).isEmpty()) {
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else if(obstacles.get(nodePointer).isWall()) {
                        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    } else if(obstacles.get(nodePointer).isRobot()) {
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    } else if(obstacles.get(nodePointer).isEmpty()) {
                        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }

                    // Draw the rectangle
                    int x = gridX + (int)i + 1;
                    int y = gridY + (int)j + 1;
                    int w = gridW/n - 2;
                    int h = gridH/n - 2;
                    clickables.add(new Clickable(x, y, w, h, ii, jj));
                    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

                    // Draw the X and Y coords
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    g.drawString("x" + ii + ", y" + jj, x+4, y+11);

                    nodePointer++;
                }
            }
        }           
    }

    // Setter for N (size)
    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    // Setter for obstacles
    public void setObstacles(LinkedList<Node> obstacles) {
        this.obstacles = obstacles;
    }

    public void addObstacle(int x, int y) {
        for(Clickable c : clickables) {
            if(c.inside(x, y)) {
                WumpusWorld.setObstacle(c.getX(), c.getY());
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeObstacle(int x, int y) {
        for(Clickable c : clickables) {
            if(c.inside(x, y)) {
                WumpusWorld.removeObstacle(c.getX(), c.getY());
            }
        }
    }

    // This class is used to allow the user to click on the grid to add an obstacle.
    private class Clickable {           
        private Rectangle rect;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Clickable(int rectX, int rectY, int width, int height, int x, int y) {
            rect = new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, width, height);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public boolean inside(int x, int y) {
            return rect.contains(x, y);
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Pathfinder.java (A* search algorithm)

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Pathfinder {
/**
 * Variable for the cost of each movement on the grid. Only for up/down/left/right movement.
 * Use {@link #setMovementCost(double)} to change from an external class.
 */
private double movementCost = 1.0;
/**
 * Storage variable for the input
 */
private Iterable<Node> iterableInput;   //Input
/**
 * Storage variable for the G-cost of the node, in A*
 * <p>
 * F = G + H
 */
private HashMap<Node,Double> gmap;      //map of travel cost
/**
 * Storage variable for the F-cost of the node, in A*
 * <p>
 * F = G + H
 */
private HashMap<Node,Double> fmap;      //map of predicted total cost
/**
 * Storage variable for a map of the paths on the grid. Every evaluated node points to its predecessor.
 */
private HashMap<Node,Node> navmap;      //map of path to each node
/**
 * Variable for which Pathfinding Heuristic to use.
 * <p>
 * Used in {@link #heuristicCost(Node, Node, int)}
 * <p>
 * default = Manhattan Distance
 * <p>
 * 1 = Diagonal Distance
 */
private static int heuristicMode;

/**
 * General Pathfinder constructor
 * <p>
 * Takes iterable input as a parameter - use anything that extends Iterable
 * 
 * @param input iterable input of nodes/boxes, such as a list
 */
public Pathfinder(Iterable<Node> input) {
    iterableInput=input;
}

/** 
 * Pathfind the correct path
 * <p>
 * There is only one public method and it returns a path in the form of a String.
 * <p>
 * Parsing the answer string is not included in this class.
 * 
 * @param start the starting node
 * @param goal  the finishing node
 * @param mode  integer for the heuristic being used
 * @return      String path of the form (0,0)(0,1)...
 */
public String pathfind(Node start, Node goal, int mode) {
    heuristicMode=mode;
    return astar(start, goal);
}

/**
 * A* method.
 * <p>
 * Algorithm adapted from Wikipedia.
 * 
 * @param start the starting node
 * @param goal  the finishing node
 * @return      String path of the form (0,0)(0,1)...
 */
private String astar(Node start, Node goal) {
    HashSet<Node> closedset = new HashSet<Node>();  //set of evaluated nodes
    HashSet<Node> openset = new HashSet<Node>();    //set of nodes to be evaluated
    openset.add(start); //first node to be evaluated
    gmap=populateHashMap(iterableInput);    //initialize HashMap of visited Nodes
    navmap=new HashMap<Node,Node>();
    fmap=populateHashMap(iterableInput);


    //Heuristic: F=G+H
    //F = total cost
    //G = path cost
    //H = heuristic cost
    //put appropriate G for start
    gmap.put(start, 0.0);
    fmap.put(start, gmap.get(start) + ManhattanDistance(start, goal));  //heuristic cost of 0

    Node current;
    while(!openset.isEmpty()) {
        current = getCheapest(openset);
        if(sameNode(current, goal))
            return constructPath(navmap,goal);
        openset.remove(current);
        closedset.add(current);

        HashSet<Node> neighbors = getNeighbors(current, heuristicMode);
        for(Node neighbor : neighbors) {
            if(closedset.contains(neighbor))
                continue;
            double temp_g = gmap.get(current) + movementCost;
            if(!openset.contains(neighbor) || temp_g<gmap.get(neighbor)) {
                navmap.put(neighbor, current);
                gmap.put(neighbor,temp_g);
                fmap.put(neighbor, gmap.get(neighbor) + heuristicCost(neighbor, goal, heuristicMode));
                if(!openset.contains(neighbor))
                    openset.add(neighbor);
            }
        }

    }
    return "failed";
}
/**
 * Set the cost for each movement.
 * <p>
 * This is for the up/down/left/right directions. The cost for moving diagonally is calculated based on that.
 * @param cost  the cost of moving up/down/left/right
 */
public void setMovementCost(double cost) {
    movementCost=cost;
}
//Cost Heuristic
/**
 * Heuristic switch function.
 * 
 * @param current   the current node
 * @param goal      the goal node
 * @param mode      the switch integer. Default for Manhattan. 1 for Diagonal.
 * @return          the cost that the switched-to heuristic has calculated
 */
private double heuristicCost(Node current, Node goal, int mode) {
    switch(mode){
    case 1: return DiagonalDistance(current, goal);
    default: return ManhattanDistance(current,goal);
    }
}
//Manhattan Distance
/**
 * Manhattan Distance heuristic.
 * <p>
 * Adapted from http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html
 * 
 * @param current   the current node
 * @param goal      the goal node
 * @return          the H-cost of the current node
 */
private double ManhattanDistance(Node current, Node goal) {
    return movementCost*(Math.abs(current.getX()-goal.getX())+Math.abs(current.getY()-goal.getY()));
}
//Diagonal Distance
/**
 * Diagonal Distance heuristic.
 * <p>
 * Adapted from http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html
 * 
 * @param current   the current node
 * @param goal      the goal node
 * @return          the H-cost of the current node
 */
private double DiagonalDistance(Node current, Node goal) {
    return movementCost*(Math.abs(current.getX()-goal.getX())+Math.abs(current.getY()-goal.getY())) + (Math.sqrt(2)*movementCost-2*movementCost)*Math.min(Math.abs(current.getX()-goal.getX()), Math.abs(current.getY()-goal.getY()));
}
//Populating the Navigation Map
//All Values set to -1.0
/**
 * Populates HashMap with parameter iterable input
 * @param input the input which gets fed into the hashmap
 */
private HashMap<Node,Double> populateHashMap(Iterable<Node> input) {
    HashMap<Node,Double> hashmap = new HashMap<Node,Double>();
    Iterator<Node> iterator=input.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        hashmap.put(iterator.next(), -1.0);
    }
    return hashmap;
}
//Getting the Cheapest Node from a HashSet
/**
 * Gets the cheapest node of the openset
 * @param openset   the set of open nodes
 * @return          the node with the cheapest F-cost
 */
private Node getCheapest(HashSet<Node> openset) {
    Iterator<Node> iterator=openset.iterator();
    Node thisNode = iterator.next();
    Node nextNode;
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        nextNode=iterator.next();
        if(fmap.get(nextNode)<fmap.get(thisNode))
            thisNode=nextNode;
    }
    return thisNode;
}
//Get the Neighbors of a Node
/**
 * Gets the neighbors of the parameter node, based on the Heuristic mode
 * 
 * @param current   the current node
 * @param mode      the Heuristic mode. See {@link #heuristicMode}
 * @return          a HashSet of the neighboring nodes
 */
private HashSet<Node> getNeighbors(Node current, int mode) {
    HashSet<Node> result = new HashSet<Node>();
    HashSet<Node> keySet=(HashSet<Node>) gmap.keySet();
    Iterator<Node> iterator=keySet.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Node thisNode=iterator.next();
        //Manhattan movement
        if(thisNode.getX()+1 == current.getX() && thisNode.getY() == current.getY())
            result.add(thisNode);
        else if(thisNode.getX()-1 == current.getX() && thisNode.getY() == current.getY())
            result.add(thisNode);
        else if(thisNode.getX() == current.getX() && thisNode.getY()+1 == current.getY())
            result.add(thisNode);
        else if(thisNode.getX() == current.getX() && thisNode.getY()-1 == current.getY())
            result.add(thisNode);
        //Diagonal movement
        else if(mode==1) {
            if(thisNode.getX()+1 == current.getX() && thisNode.getY()+1 == current.getY())
                result.add(thisNode);
            else if(thisNode.getX()+1 == current.getX() && thisNode.getY()-1 == current.getY())
                result.add(thisNode);
            else if(thisNode.getX()-1 == current.getX() && thisNode.getY()+1 == current.getY())
                result.add(thisNode);
            else if(thisNode.getX()-1 == current.getX() && thisNode.getY()-1 == current.getY())
                result.add(thisNode);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
//Same Nodes
//Checks whether the nodes are the same, based on their x and y
/**
 * Checks for node similarity. This is included here in order to reduce class inter-dependency
 * <p>
 * Compares the results from getX() and getY() for each node.
 * @param thisNode  the first compared node
 * @param otherNode the second compared node
 * @return          TRUE if their coordinates are the same
 */
private boolean sameNode(Node thisNode, Node otherNode) {
    return thisNode.getX()==otherNode.getX() && thisNode.getY()==otherNode.getY();
}
//Path Constructor
//Returns String of Nodes in the form of (0,0)(0,1)...
/**
 * Constructs a path from the parameter node and the now valued {@link #navmap}
 * <p>
 * Returns String with tokens built in {@link #toNodeString(Node)}
 * 
 * @param hashmap   the navmap
 * @param last      the goal -or- last node
 * @return          the String of nodes leading to the parameter node
 */
private String constructPath(HashMap<Node,Node> hashmap, Node last) {
    String t;
    if(hashmap.containsKey(last)) {
        t = constructPath(hashmap, hashmap.get(last));
        return (t + last);
    }
    else {
        return toNodeString(last);
    }
}
//Nodes to Strings in the form of "(x,y)"
/**
 * Turns a node into a String
 * 
 * @param a the parameter node
 * @return  the node represented in the String form of "(x,y)"
 */
private String toNodeString(Node a) {
    return "("+a.getX()+","+a.getY()+")";
}
}
```

Node.java (Node class)

```
public class Node {
private int x;
private int y;
private boolean isEmpty, isWall, isRobot, isGoal;
/**
 * Basic constructor.
 * <p>
 * Takes coordinates x, y, and box type.
 * 
 * @param x     the X coordinate
 * @param y     the Y coordinate
 * @param type  String for the type: "empty", "wall", "robot", "goal"
 */
public Node(int x, int y, String type) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    isEmpty=false;
    isWall=false;
    isRobot=false;
    isGoal=false;
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
        isEmpty=true;
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("wall"))
        isWall=true;
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("robot"))
        isRobot=true;
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("goal"))
        isGoal=true;
}
/**
 * Gets the x coordinate.
 * 
 * @return the X coordinate
 */
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
/**
 * Gets the y coordinate.
 * 
 * @return the Y coordinate
 */
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

/**
 * Checks if empty.
 * 
 * @return true if empty
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return isEmpty;
}
/**
 * Checks if is wall.
 * 
 * @return true if wall
 */
public boolean isWall() {
    return isWall;
}
/**
 * Checks if is robot.
 * 
 * @return true if robot
 */
public boolean isRobot() {
    return isRobot;
}
/**
 * Checks if is goal.
 * @return true if goal
 */
public boolean isGoal() {
    return isGoal;
}
/**
 * Sets the type of the box
 * <p>
 * Does nothing with invalid input
 * 
 * @param type String representing the type: "empty", "wall", "robot", "goal"
 */
public void setType(String type) {
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("empty")) {
        isWall=false;
        isEmpty=true;
        isRobot=false;
        isGoal=false;
    }
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("wall")) {
        isWall=true;
        isEmpty=false;
        isRobot=false;
        isGoal=false;
    }
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("robot")) {
        isWall=false;
        isEmpty=false;
        isRobot=true;
        isGoal=false;
    }
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("goal")) {
        isWall=false;
        isEmpty=false;
        isRobot=false;
        isGoal=true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should look into MVC, as it tends to avoid this type of problem. If WumpusWorld is wrapped in a thread/extends the thread class, then it will run separately from the Event Dispatch Thread. However, you do NOT want to modify the GUI from that thread unless you are passing a reference of the main "view" to a controller, then telling the controller to "update" the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses a dedicated thread to manage GUI and related events, which is called [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). You can't execute an intensive task directly inside a `ActionListener` callback because this would execute on the Swing thread and make the GUI unresponsive.

You should use a different thread to manage this, there are many possible solution, like using a normal Thread that calls `repaint()` or a `SwingWorker`. Take a look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing_summary) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) for further informations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Much appreciated. I'll have a look at these links and hopefully pick an appropriate solution. :)

Comment: Hi sorry, but SwingWorker only speeds the processing up.  My question was how I can get it to process the method WumpusWorld.run via the start button in the first place.  I click Start, and it does nothing at all.  It doesn't freeze until completion.